# С# выборка массива из *.txt по заданному условию

Tags: c#

Имеется файл типа *.txt как внедренный ресурс.

```
11000 Иванов Олег
11000 Сидоров Петр
12000 Лисицин Витя
13000 Белов Евгений
11000 Синицин Павел
```

Необходимо выбрать все фамилии по условию "11000"

```
protected static void LoadCodesAndNames(string file, out string[] codes, out string[] units, out string[] names)
{
    string t = Convert.ToString(11000);

    var lCodes = new List<string>();
    var lNames = new List<string>();
    var lUnits = new List<string>();
    var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    using (var f = new StreamReader(assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Resq.Devi.Impl.txt")))
        while (!f.EndOfStream)
        {
            var spl = f.ReadLine().Split(new[] { "\t" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            if (spl.Length == 3 && lCodes.Equals(t))
            {
                lCodes.Add(spl[0]);
                lUnits.Add(spl[1]);
                lNames.Add(spl[2]);
            }
        }           
    codes = lUnits.ToArray();
    units = lUnits.ToArray();
    names = lNames.ToArray();
}
```

Цикл не берет ни одного варианта файл именно в том виде как указан в начале поста. Допустим 10 строк по 3 значения через Табуляцию(код, фамилия, имя).

Comment: Что за "codeA" ?

Comment: текстовое поле в xml файле. его заполняют - кодом пользователя, к примеру 001. из справочника пользователей необходимо выбрать всех пользователей с параметром 001.

Comment: lCodes.Any(x=>x==t) попробуйте.

Comment: спасибо бошое - добавил, ошибок нет, но не берет ни одного значения =(

Comment: а у вас в файле точно все разделено табами, а не обычными пробелами? возможно не происходит сплит и на spl.Length == 3 оно проходит мимо, поставьте breakpoint и проверьте

Comment: @shinso А есть возможность заменить табуляцию на другой символ? Например как в csv на точку с запятой. Просто это нигде не считается символом разделения, и как видите, нельзя просто взять и указать в функцию split.

Comment: Спасибо большое) я уже разобрался с файлом все окей, я проверял lCodes - а он там только считает их количество) проверку нужно было задавать на переменную spl. Теперь нужно только подключить глобальную а не локальную переменную вместо t. Сейчас читаю как это сделать.

Comment: `var result = File.ReadAllLines("testFile.txt").Select(x => { var ar = x.Split(); return new { Id = int.Parse(ar[0]), Surname = ar[1], Name = ar[2] }; }).Where(x => x.Id == 11000);`

Answer (score 0):

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("dwd.txt").ToList();
            var result = lines.Select(x =>
            {
                var values = x.Split(" ");
                return new { Price = int.Parse(values[0]), Name = values[1] };
            }).Where(x => x.Price == 11000);
```

Comment: Зачем тут `.ToList()` и указание пробела у `Split()`?